# are there no equivalents to tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter for pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I've installed a handful of docker containers for this purpose but have run into a dead end. I can't seem to find something like the tensorflow docker containers for pytorch. Ideally I could install a container up to the Google Colab specs so I could run torch or tensorflow.

What am I missing? I feel like this should be easy to find.

Comment: I wouldn't expect something like this to be available, mostly because it is quite straightforward to extend the pytorch/latest container with jupyter. Is there any specific functionality in this container that you want beyond Jupyter+(your dl framework)?

Comment: Ah ok, this is putting me on the right track. So I understand that pip installs won't persist when I reboot the image, how do I add or "extend" the container w jupyter?

Comment: In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37271687/4228275) you'll find how to commit changes in a container to a new image.

Comment: BTW, you can take a look at the [commands history of the tf:latest-gpu-jupyter](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/latest-gpu-jupyter/images/sha256-f5227081c37421d8ed9ec7e08968a047794fb7b3cebbb2a6ce7cd286ed6a346c?context=explore) (check command #38 onwards) to understand how to install and expose jupyter.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you!